# How to disable vote menus in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

This may seem an odd thing to want. But I literally don't want to see or participate in CS:GO votes.

- They obstruct my screen
- They distract me
- Sometimes they freeze on screen
- They keep getting me killed

These votes get me killed constantly, today I was trying to snipe someone and a player kick menu popped up and I tried to press F2 and I got sausage fingers and ended up getting trapped in some weird grey windows or Steam recording menu. It was stealing my keyboard and mouse input and I couldn't quit from it, so I was frozen there hammering esc in vain. Obviously I died. Now this isn't the first time I've been killed by these votes.

The votes are never about anything sensible either, it's always someone insulted someone's mum and called her fatso or something, and now fatso junior is trying to get the other person kicked. Or 3 seconds into a game someone wants to change map.

It would be easier if there was a way to totally disable the votes in CS:GO altogether, so that the vote menu doesn't popup? Is there some way to do that on my CS:GO game client with public servers?

Comment: I remember that this has been asked for years and years, but I guess Valve did nothing apparently. You cannot disable it, nor make it transparent. Funny enough, TF2's vote menu is (IIRC) transparent. I wonder why CS:GO's vote menu isn't.

Comment: It feels like this is the sort of thing there should be a community made patch for, but then would it trigger like a vac ban or something?

Comment: I think so. Anything that advantages player would make you get banned, if I'm not mistaken how VAC works.

Comment: It would likely trigger an automatic VAC ban by the system itself, as modifying game files is an easily-noticed no-no. Maybe you pressed `~` and opened the console? Could try to rebind voting so it's more easily accessible.